# SQL Join another SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I've managed to put together a query for SCCM and MDT that gives me computer installed on a specific location for the last 7 days, based on default gateway.
I also managed to JOIN information from another table.

```
SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
      ,DH.[Computername]
      ,DH.[AssetTag]
      ,DH.[Serialnumber]
      ,DH.[Manufacturer]
      ,DH.[Model]
      ,DH.[Role]
      ,DH.[StartTime]
      ,DH.[EndTime]
      ,DH.[DefaultGateway]
      ,CIL.[Username]
FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate() AND 
        (DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.10.1' OR DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.20.1')
            ORDER BY Starttid DESC
```

What I'm trying to do now is to add yet another column based on SCCM OSD collection.
I have a working code to give me all devices in those collection

```
SELECT COL.Name FROM v_R_System SD
JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership FCM ON SD.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
JOIN v_Collection COL ON FCM.CollectionID = COL.CollectionID
WHERE (COL.CollectionID = 'XXXXXXX1' OR COL.CollectionID = 'XXXXXXX2' OR COL.CollectionID = 'XXXXXXX3')
```

Running my second query gives me output like this:
[image]

But however I try to join this with above It either gives me nothing or to much devices.
The problem is that I don't now how to merge this and still keep the filter (WHERE-section)

One example I've tried is:

```
SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
      ,DH.[Computername]
      ,DH.[HBGAssetTag]
      ,DH.[Serialnumber]
      ,DH.[Manufacturer]
      ,DH.[Model]
      ,DH.[Role]
      ,DH.[StartTime]
      ,DH.[EndTime]
      ,DH.[DefaultGateway]
      ,CIL.[Username]
      ,COL.[Name]
FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
JOIN [v_FullCollectionMembership] FCM ON DH.[ResourceID] = FCM.[ResourceID]
JOIN [v_Collection] COL ON DH.[ResourceID] = COL.[CollectionID]
LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate() AND 
        (DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.10.1' OR DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.20.1') AND
            (COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX1' OR COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX2' OR COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX3')
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XXXXXXX1' to data type int.

Completion time: 2021-06-14T15:05:41.5142960+02:00
```

I have tried to create another LEFT JOIN and just add the data from that one, but that didn't work either. I need to sort out as I do in the original query.

Anyone who might be able to point me into the correct direction?

**Second try**

```
SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
      ,DH.[Computername]
      ,DH.[HBGAssetTag]
      ,DH.[Serialnumber]
      ,DH.[Manufacturer]
      ,DH.[Model]
      ,DH.[Role]
      ,DH.[StartTime]
      ,DH.[EndTime]
      ,DH.[DefaultGateway]
      ,CIL.[Username]
      ,COL.[Name]
FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
JOIN [v_FullCollectionMembership] FCM ON DH.[ResourceID] = FCM.[ResourceID]
JOIN [v_Collection] COL ON FCM.[CollectionID] = COL.[CollectionID]
LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate() AND 
        (DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.10.1' OR DH.[DefaultGateway] = '192.168.20.1') AND
            (COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX1' OR COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX2' OR COL.[CollectionID] = 'XXXXXXX3')
```

**Third try**

```
SELECT Q1.[ResourceID]
, Q1.[Computername]
, Q1.[AssetTag]
, Q1.[Serialnumber]
, Q1.[Manufacturer]
, Q1.[Model]
, Q1.[Role]
, Q1.[StartTime]
, Q1.[EndTime]
, Q1.[DefaultGateway]
, Q1.[Username]
, Q2.[Name] AS 'CollectionName'

FROM (
    SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
    , DH.[Computername]
    , DH.[AssetTag]
    , DH.[Serialnumber]
    , DH.[Manufacturer]
    , DH.[Model]
    , DH.[Role]
    , DH.[StartTime]
    , DH.[EndTime]
    , DH.[DefaultGateway]
    , CIL.[Username]
    
    FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
      LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
      AND DH.[DefaultGateway] IN ('192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1')
  ) Q1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SD.[ResourceID]
    , COL.Name 
    FROM [v_R_System] SD
      INNER JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH ON SD.[ResourceID] = DH.[ResourceID]
      INNER JOIN [v_FullCollectionMembership] FCM ON SD.[ResourceID] = FCM.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN [v_Collection] COL ON FCM.[CollectionID] = COL.[CollectionID]
    WHERE COL.[CollectionID] in ('XXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXX3')
  ) Q2

ORDER BY DH.[StartTime] DESC
```

Shows red error at Q2 see attached image:
[image]

And at "ORDER":

[image]

The error message:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT Q1.[ResourceID]
,Q1.[Computername]
,Q1.[AssetTag]
,Q1.[Serialnumber]
,Q1.[Manufacturer]
,Q1.[Model]
,Q1.[Role]
,Q1.[StartTime]
,Q1.[EndTime]
,Q1.[DefaultGateway]
,Q1.[Username]
,Q2.[Name] AS 'CollectionName'

FROM (
    SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
    ,DH.[Computername]
    ,DH.[HBGAssetTag]
    ,DH.[Serialnumber]
    ,DH.[Manufacturer]
    ,DH.[Model]
    ,DH.[Role]
    ,DH.[StartTime]
    ,DH.[EndTime]
    ,DH.[DefaultGateway]
    ,CIL.[Username]
    
    FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
      LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE DH.[StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
      AND DH.[DefaultGateway] IN ('192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1')
  ) AS Q1

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SD.[ResourceID]
    ,COL.Name 
    FROM [v_R_System] SD
      INNER JOIN [v_FullCollectionMembership] FCM ON SD.[ResourceID] = FCM.[ResourceID]
      INNER JOIN [v_Collection] COL ON FCM.[CollectionID] = COL.[CollectionID]
    WHERE COL.[CollectionID] IN ('XXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXX3')
  ) AS Q2
  ON Q1.[ResourceID] = Q2.[ResourceID]

ORDER BY Q1.[StartTime] DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second query is working?
What is the type of DH.[ResourceID] and COL.[CollectionID]?

Comment: I've updated my question with A picture showing that my second query works standalone.

Comment: And what type is collection ID? because it seems that in the third query something is casted differently.

Comment: If XXXXXXX1 is a number, try to do something like CAST('XXXXXXX1' as int)

Comment: Both FCM- and COL.CollectionID are nvarchar.
They contain both characters and digits.

Comment: And DH.[ResourceID]? Because it seems that one variable that you are comparing with CollectionID  is an integer

Comment: DH.Resource is an integer just as SD and FCM.ResourceID are on the working second query.

Comment: But in the second query you are joining CollectionID with CollectionID and ResourceID  with ResourceID, not ResourceID with CollectionID

Comment: You are absolutely right.
I updated my question with a "second try".
Alltough it seems that I am thinking all wrong.
The idea of adding the second query is to for those devices found by the first query add in another column if it exists in one or more of the three Collections XXXXXXX1-3.
The "second try" gives me only those computers that exists in one of the collections and not those not existing in any of them. It doesn't gives me the information if the computer exists in more than one of them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dougp:s answer and managed to get it working.

**SOLUTION**

```
<!-- begin snippet: -->

<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    SELECT Q1.[ResourceID]
        ,Q1.[Computername]
        ,Q1.[AssetTag]
        ,Q1.[Serialnumber]
        ,Q1.[Manufacturer]
        ,Q1.[Model]
        ,Q1.[Role]
        ,Q1.[StartTime]
        ,Q1.[EndTime]
        ,Q1.[DefaultGateway]
        ,Q1.[Username]
        ,Q2.[Name] AS 'CollectionName'

    FROM (
        SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
        ,DH.[Computername]
        ,DH.[HBGAssetTag]
        ,DH.[Serialnumber]
        ,DH.[Manufacturer]
        ,DH.[Model]
        ,DH.[Role]
        ,DH.[StartTime]
        ,DH.[EndTime]
        ,DH.[DefaultGateway]
        ,CIL.[Username]
        
        FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
          LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
        WHERE DH.[StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
          AND DH.[DefaultGateway] IN ('192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1')
        ) AS Q1

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT SD.[ResourceID]
        ,COL.Name 
        FROM [v_R_System] SD
          INNER JOIN [v_FullCollectionMembership] FCM ON SD.[ResourceID] = FCM.[ResourceID]
          INNER JOIN [v_Collection] COL ON FCM.[CollectionID] = COL.[CollectionID]
        WHERE COL.[CollectionID] IN ('XXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXX3')
        ) AS Q2
        ON Q1.[ResourceID] = Q2.[ResourceID]

        ORDER BY Q1.[StartTime] DESC

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be lacking a field to join on.  Plus, I suspect what you are trying to do is add the collection name for each resource, if the collection name exists.  Try changing your second query to...

```
SELECT SD.ResourceID
, COL.Name 
FROM v_R_System SD
  INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership FCM ON SD.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
  INNER JOIN v_Collection COL ON FCM.CollectionID = COL.CollectionID
WHERE COL.CollectionID in ('XXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXX3')
```

From there, you combine the queries.  This is a brute force simple way:

```
SELECT Q1.[ResourceID]
, Q1.[Computername]
, Q1.[AssetTag]
, Q1.[Serialnumber]
, Q1.[Manufacturer]
, Q1.[Model]
, Q1.[Role]
, Q1.[StartTime]
, Q1.[EndTime]
, Q1.[DefaultGateway]
, Q1.[Username]
, Q2.[Name] AS 'CollectionName'

FROM (
    SELECT DH.[ResourceID]
    , DH.[Computername]
    , DH.[AssetTag]
    , DH.[Serialnumber]
    , DH.[Manufacturer]
    , DH.[Model]
    , DH.[Role]
    , DH.[StartTime]
    , DH.[EndTime]
    , DH.[DefaultGateway]
    , CIL.[Username]
    , Startid
    
    FROM [MDT].[dbo].[DeploymentHistory] DH
      LEFT JOIN [MDT].[dbo].[ComputerImportLog] CIL ON DH.[Computername] = CIL.[Computername]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
      AND DH.[DefaultGateway] IN ('192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1')
  ) Q1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SD.ResourceID
    , COL.Name 
    FROM v_R_System SD
      INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership FCM ON SD.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN v_Collection COL ON FCM.CollectionID = COL.CollectionID
    WHERE COL.CollectionID in ('XXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXX3')
  ) Q2

ORDER BY Starttid DESC
```

This can be done without using subqueries, but this sort of documents your thought process.  (I want to see the results of this joined with the results of that.)  So it's a good place to start.  Once you see the results you seek, then streamline the query.

While not always required, it is good practice to qualify your columns.  For example, I don't know where `Startid` came from, so I am not 100% certain about this code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe i'm very close to an solution now.
Altough it gives my error at the end. (please see my original post were I added my "third try" and it's errors.
The Starttid is removed. I have tested a lot and forgot to remove it.

Comment: I think the issue still remaining has something to do with the "FROM (" part.
As far as I can see the FROM-section ends at ") Q1".
But I havn't been able to figure out how to format it to include the "LEFT OUTER JOIN" into the FROM-section so that the ") Q2" also works.

Comment: Please provide a SQL statement that will generate some basic data to work with and create table statement(s).